# If $H$ is the closure of the set of solenoidal smooth vecor fields in $L^2$ and $P_H$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $H$, then $P_HH_0^1⊆H_0^1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fluid-dynamics

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $\mathcal V:=\left\{\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d):\nabla\cdot\phi=0\right\}$ and $$H:=\overline{\mathcal V}^{\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}}$$
- $\operatorname P_H$ denote the orthogonal projection from $L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ onto $H$

In [Remark 1.6](https://books.google.de/books?id=CKYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22let+us+write%22+%22for+the+orthogonal+projector+in%22&source=bl&ots=0pyIUVb2Ng&sig=BMr-2ov3ri6PT8_haso4UdmZoX0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWzKGc3u_QAhXHJSwKHdjsByoQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22let%20us%20write%22%20%22for%20the%20orthogonal%20projector%20in%22&f=false) of *Navier-Stokes Equations: Theory and Numerical Analysis* by *Roger Temam*, the author is stating that $\text P_HH_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)\subseteq H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$. I don't think that this is trivial. How can we prove it?

Comment: I'm afraid your questions are not quite up to research level and I suggest you read up on Sobolev spaces (density, embedding, extension, restriction, characterization in the frequency space, etc) from a textbook.

Comment: @FanZheng Do you know the answer?

Comment: I'm only remarking that this is not the typical question asked on mathoverflow; it would be more suitable on math stackexchange.

Comment: @FanZheng I've asked this on MSE, but didn't get an answer.

Comment: Could you post the link here?

Comment: This does not seem true. Are your sure the source you cite really says that?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I've provided a link to the relevant page: [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=CKYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22let+us+write%22+%22for+the+orthogonal+projector+in%22&source=bl&ots=0pyIUVb2Ng&sig=BMr-2ov3ri6PT8_haso4UdmZoX0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWzKGc3u_QAhXHJSwKHdjsByoQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22let%20us%20write%22%20%22for%20the%20orthogonal%20projector%20in%22&f=false).

Comment: The link directs to a page that is not accessible. In any case, my copy of Temam's book does not have a Lemma 1.6. It has a Remark 1.6, which says that $P_H$ maps $H^1$ to itself, not $H^1_0$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Strange, it's accessible for me. However, I've actually meant Remark 1.6; I'm sorry for the confusion. You're right, it says that what you've written. I thought the same would be true for $H_0^1$. In either case, it's not clear to me why $\text P_H$ maps $H^1$ to itself.

Comment: I think I see your problem now. In my copy of Temam, it says: "let us assume that $u\in H^1(\Omega)$, then ${\rm div}\,u\in H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$...," which does not make sense. It should read "... then ${\rm div}\,u\in L^2(\Omega)$, and hence $p\in H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy My problem is that I want the operator $B$ on page 44, equation (6.9), of *Navier-Stokes Equations and Nonlinear Functional Analysis* ([here](http://tinyurl.com/hz2ed7w) is a link to that page) to be a bounded operator from $V_\gamma$ to $V_\alpha$, $\gamma-\alpha<1$, where $V_r:=\mathcal D(A^r)$ and $A$ denotes the Stokes operator on $H$ with $\mathcal D(A)=V\cap H^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ and $V:=\overline{\mathcal V}^{\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{H^1(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}}=H\cap H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$. Actually, I need $\gamma=1$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy And that's why I've hoped that I can choose $\alpha=1/2$, $V_{1/2}=V$. That would be the case, if I could apply the same argumentation as in the proof of Lemma 6.1 (on the referenced page 44) with $E_m=H^m\cap H$ replaced by $H_0^m\cap H$. (In any case, it's not even clear to me that $\text P_H$ maps $H^1$ to itself. How can we prove it?)

Comment: The argument that $P_H$ maps $H^1$ to itself is given in Temam's book, and I shall not repeat it beyond pointing out the correction as I did before. $P_H$ does not map $H^m_0$ to itself. It preserves regularity, but not the boundary conditions.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy The argument is in the book? Where?

Comment: It says "In the proof of Theorem 1.5, let us assume ..." This is an invitation to following along the proof of Theorem 1.5, subject to the additional explanations that follow. This will be my last response. This site is not for tutoring.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I tink that the conclusion $p\in H^2(\Omega)$ is wrong. Of course, $$\Delta p=\nabla\cdot u\in L^2(\Omega)$$ and hence $p$ has a weak Laplacian in $L^2(\Omega)$. But that doesn't imply that the distributional partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^2p}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$, $i\ne j$, are in $L^2(\Lambda)$ too.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Let me note that I'm aware of the fact that by well-known elliptic regularity theory we actually can conclude $p\in H^2(\Omega)$ if, for example, $\partial\Omega\in C^2$. But the $\Omega$ I'm interested in is only bounded and open with a Lipschitz boundary.